# Adding title to the PlotSymbol

Tags: ios, core-plot

[image]

Is it possible to set a title instead of A `CPTPlotSymbol` ? I want to display the co-ordinates instead of a symbol.Here is the screen shot.I want a label where , there is a circle symbol plot in the screen shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `plotSymbol` to `nil` to remove the symbols from the plot. You want to use data labels to label the points. If you just want to show the y-coordinate, set a `labelTextStyle` and `labelFormatter`. The plot will create and display labels automatically using the given style and number format.

If you need more complex labels (e.g., showing both x and y coordinates), you can make custom labels. Implement the `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method. This method can return any `CPTLayer`, so you have a lot of flexibility. For simple text labels, create a string with the label text and display it in a `CPTTextLayer`. The plot will position the label for you and keep it aligned with the data point if it moves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try it out.And yeah i want to display the labels as the x and y co-ordinates only.( `e.g (20,50)`).

Comment: For implementing this , i am getting this error.
`set objc-non-blocking-mode off 
to override this check if you are sure your call doesn't use the ObjC runtime.`

Comment: Now i want to add the labels on the right side as i've added labels on the y axis to the left side.Is there nay way to do so??Please help me.

Comment: You want labels on both sides of the y-axis? The easiest way would be to add another y-axis and configure it similar to the existing one. Set all of its line styles to `nil` so it is invisible and put the labels on the other side.